# JQuery: How to get all of a selector's html attributes in one statement, as a string?

Tags: jquery, html, string, header

I've got a div that looks like this:

```
<div id="exampleDiv" class="class1 class2" title="example title"></div>
```

I've selected with JQuery using this statement:

```
var $div = $('#exampleDiv');
```

What I'd like to get is a string of the tag itself as html, so that I actually get:

```
"<div id='exampleDiv' class='class1'....", etc.
```

Does anyone know of a JQuery function I could use that does this, given the selector? I'm thinking something like `$div.htmlHeader()` or something like that.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please check out my function, though it has been downvoted. Don't know why?!? It works, I'll promise.

Comment: @aefxx - You do know why (though I didn't down-vote you). You started with **Not to see the wood for the trees?** Then gave solutions that didn't work.

Comment: @patrick I already apologized for not grasping the needs of the author, edited and solved his problem. What more could you possibly want?

Comment: @aefxx - To not pretend as though you don't know why you were originally down-voted. (Though, as I stated, I didn't down-vote you.)

Comment: @patrick As I said, I APOLOGIZED - btw the saying wasn't ment offensive. Nevermind.

Comment: @aefxx - By the way, your solution has an extra `)` at the end, so it still isn't right. You shouldn't down-vote **Sean** when he got his correct the first time.

Comment: @aefxx - Came across as smug. No need for that here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Clone the element into a new div, remove the clone's children, and print the parent div's html:

```
var html = $("<div/>").append($("#exampleDiv").clone().empty()).html();
```

If the element you want to print has a lot of descendents and you don't want to incur the cost of cloning the entire hierarchy, and if you don't mind briefly leaving the safety of jQuery's DOM interface, you could do this instead:

```
var html = $("<div/>").append($("#exampleDiv")[0].cloneNode(false)).html();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
$.fn.tagonly = function() {
    return $('<div/>').append($(this).clone().empty())
        .html().replace(/>(.|[\r\n])*$/ig, '>');
};
```

**Edit** Fixed the extra `)` and the newline issue. Thanks patrick.

Comment: @aefxx - Your solution has an extra `)` at the end. Also, I don't think `.*` will match line-breaks. Looks good otherwise. Better than my solution.